# ApiResource attribute gives Compile Error: Constant expression contains invalid operations

Tags: api-platform.com

I'm trying to expose only some endpoints with API Platform as explained here: https://api-platform.com/docs/v2.7/core/operations/.

If I just use the ApiResource attribute, I get the expected result (i.e. the default CRUD endpoints).

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use App\Repository\MyclassRepository;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: MyclassRepository::class)]
#[ApiResource]
class Myclass
{
}
```

But none of the options to show only some operations work.

This one:

```
#[ApiResource(operations=[
    new Get(),
    new GetCollection()
])]
```

... just outputs "No operations defined in spec!" on /api/docs. It also makes VSCode angry about "operation=":

```
Expression is not writable.intelephense(1024)
Undefined constant 'App\Entity\operations'.intelephense(1011)
Syntax error: unexpected token '='PHP(PHP2014)
```

This one:

```
#[ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new Get(),
        new GetCollection()
    ]
)]
```

... produces the error "Compile Error: Constant expression contains invalid operations".

- The project is running locally on Docker php:8.0-fpm with "api-platform/core": "^2.7".
- The appropriate "use" statements are present.
- I tried different combinations of methods and config (e.g. uriTemplate).

I also tried using api-platform ^2.6 with :

```
#[ApiResource(
    collectionOperations: ['get'],
    itemOperations: ['get'],
)]
```

... which produces the error "Unknown named parameter $collectionOperations".

What am I missing?

Thanks!!

Comment: Nevermind sorry! I finally stumbled upon a post that mentionned PHP 8.1 is needed, not 8.0 -_-

Comment: I also encountered this issue but your suggestion did not work for me.

Comment: @shaho1090 With PHP8.1, the 3rd approach in my post works i.e. #[ApiResource( operations: [ new Get(), new Post() ] )]

Comment: you are right, my old Phpstorm worked based on PHP Language Level up to 8.0 and continued to alarm me about that lines of codes, I updated it and set the PHP version to 8.2 which is a newer version and those alarms disappeared. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API Platform requires PHP 8.1, not 8.0. After upgrading, this works:

```
#[ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new Get(),
        new GetCollection()
    ]
)]
```